# Can I use the free version of Construct 2 on Gamejolt?

Tags: licensing, construct-2

According to Scirra's website, I am not permitted to use the free version of Construct 2 for commercial purposes. If I host a game I created with the free version of Construct 2 on Gamejolt where I can earn money on the game, am I violating Scirra's terms?

Comment: If you wouldn't want to get caught doing it or if you have ANY doubts about doing it, you should probably consult with one of the party's involved (Scirra) or a lawyer that will take the blame.

Comment: Consider where you should be asking these types of questions too. Although you're making a game, your real question is about a license agreement (which is not specific to game development). While there isn't a law SE, the programmers SE is probably the next best place to ask about software licenses, and you can find the answer already there: [What constitutes “commercial purposes”?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/88301/what-constitutes-commercial-purposes)

Answer (score 2):

**I am not a lawyer**, but that sounds like "commercial purposes" to me.

However, the best option in this case is to **consult a lawyer**.

Comment: [Commercial purposes](http://definitions.uslegal.com/u/used-for-commercial-purposes/), if you're doing it for profit, it's commercial.

Answer (score 2):

From [Licensing Agreement](https://www.scirra.com/store/licensing#license2):

> The Free Edition is permitted for use by anyone for non commercial use. Commercial use counts as but is not limited to: use within any business (other than limited testing for suitability), generating advertising revenue, selling or licensing generated content or intention or capability to generate revenue.

From [official Scirra tutorial page](https://www.scirra.com/tutorials/482/publishing-your-construct-2-game-on-game-jolt)

> By default, games uploaded to Game Jolt have ad revenue sharing enabled, which may pose a problem for Free Edition users, who are not allowed to earn money from their games. Fortunately, Game Jolt recently introduced an option to disable ads for your games. Thanks to this, Free Edition users can feel free to publish their creations on Game Jolt. To disable ads, upload your game and go to its dashboard. Then, go to Settings and switch Show ads? to Off.